# Spring Boot replacing application property on startup

Tags: spring-boot

In my Spring Boot application I need to replace some properties defined in application.yml with the ones from AWS Secrets Manager. I am aware of Spring Cloud AWS Secrets Manager project, but for various reasons using it is not an option for me. I decided implement a listener which would listen to ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent and replace all the properties I need. The problem is that I am getting a strange exception which I cannot explain. Here is my code (It is a bit messy since I experimented with it.

I know by experimenting that the PropertySource of application.yml is always instance of MapPropertySource
Replacing property within PropertySource is not an option since the map within it is immutable, I need to replace the entire PropertySource with a new one containing modified properties
The properties within PropertySource map are instances of OriginTrackedValue, so I need to construct them

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class PropertiesListener implements ApplicationListener<ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent> {

  @Override
  public void onApplicationEvent(ApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent event) {
      ConfigurableEnvironment environment = event.getEnvironment();
      MutablePropertySources propertySources = environment.getPropertySources();
      Iterator<PropertySource<?>> iterator = propertySources.iterator();
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
          PropertySource<?> propertySource = iterator.next();   
          PropertySource<?> replacement = replaceWithSecrets(propertySource);
          if (replacement != null) {
              propertySources.remove(propertySource.getName());
              propertySources.addLast(replacement);
          }
      }
  }

  private PropertySource<?> replaceWithSecrets(PropertySource<?> originalPropertySource) {
      boolean needsReplacement = false;
      Map<String, Object> newMap = new HashMap<>();
      MapPropertySource map = null;
      if (originalPropertySource instanceof MapPropertySource) {
          map = (MapPropertySource) originalPropertySource;
          for (Map.Entry<String, Object> entry : map.getSource().entrySet()) {
              if (needsReplacement(entry.getValue().toString())) {
                 Origin origin = OriginLookup.getOrigin(originalPropertySource, entry.getKey());
                 OriginTrackedValue val = OriginTrackedValue.of(replaceWithSecret(entry.getValue().toString()), origin);
                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), val);
                needsReplacement = true;
            } else {

                newMap.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
            }

        
    }
    if (needsReplacement) {
        return new MapPropertySource(originalPropertySource.getName(), Collections.unmodifiableMap(newMap));
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

On startup my application throws an exception

```
12:51:25.523 [main] ERROR o.s.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to process import candidates for configuration class [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:610)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.access$800(ConfigurationClassParser.java:111)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.lambda$processGroupImports$1(ConfigurationClassParser.java:812)
    at java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1257)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorGroupingHandler.processGroupImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:809)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser$DeferredImportSelectorHandler.process(ConfigurationClassParser.java:780)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:193)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:331)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:247)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:311)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:112)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:746)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:564)
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:144)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:769)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:426)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:326)
    at com.ewc.inventory.EwcInventoryApplication.main(EwcInventoryApplication.java:24)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error processing condition on org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.JpaBaseConfiguration$JpaWebConfiguration
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:60)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConditionEvaluator.shouldSkip(ConditionEvaluator.java:108)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:226)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processMemberClasses(ConfigurationClassParser.java:372)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:272)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processImports(ConfigurationClassParser.java:600)
    ... 21 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.boot.origin.OriginTrackedValue] to type [java.lang.String]
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:195)
    at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.convert(GenericConversionService.java:175)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractPropertyResolver.convertValueIfNecessary(AbstractPropertyResolver.java:265)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:91)
    at org.springframework.core.env.PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.getProperty(PropertySourcesPropertyResolver.java:62)
    at org.springframework.core.env.AbstractEnvironment.getProperty(AbstractEnvironment.java:588)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.collectProperties(OnPropertyCondition.java:140)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition$Spec.access$000(OnPropertyCondition.java:105)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.determineOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:91)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.OnPropertyCondition.getMatchOutcome(OnPropertyCondition.java:55)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.condition.SpringBootCondition.matches(SpringBootCondition.java:47)
    ... 27 common frames omitted
```

The root cause seems to be

```
org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.boot.origin.OriginTrackedValue] to type [java.lang.String]
at org.springframework.core.convert.support.GenericConversionService.handleConverterNotFound(GenericConversionService.java:322)
```

I tried to change the code around, by adding the string directly to PropertySource map instead of OriginTrackedValue, construct OriginTrackedValue in different way, but I am still getting the same exception. I am getting it even if I construct new MapPropertySource with the map from old property source.

Comment: You don't need to replace it. You only need to add a `PropertySource` with a higher order so that it is consulted first. That being said I would strongly suggest using the Spring Cloud solution instead of (re)building your own solution.

Comment: @M.Deinum That was it. Thank you very much